# Command ant not found

Tags: linux

```
XYZ@xyz-vml-0010:~/Desktop/Rat2021/Rat$ ant build
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.10.1//bin/ant: 1: exec: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_172/bin/java: Permission denied
```

I am getting permission error, solution?

Comment: Please be more carefully when asking questions. You confuse people. Your title and your actual question say different things. Can you [edit] your question and provide more information? What are the permissions on that `java` from the error message (use `ls -l`)? Can you run it manually? If not, is it an executable file? If so, check permissions on the whole path to `java` and use `chmod` as needed. If it's a directory, your `JAVA_HOME` may be set wrong. Just guessing though. It would also always help to include what you've already tried to solve this. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **sudo** command?
write **sudo** before your command I think it will work

Comment: Yes tried , if I use sudo then getting  Command 'ant' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install ant # version 1.10.9, or

apt install ant

See 'snap info ant' for additional verstons.

root@txta-ml-0010:/home/lxtauser# 1

Comment: You should never need to `sudo` for regular commands. Running java (or ant) is nothing limited to the superuser. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root